# Webklex\PHPIMAP Modern Auth Not Working 365

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, imap

As with most people, Microsoft are turning off basic authentication. This means we need to use Modern Auth to retrieve emails from a mailbox.

However,when we retrie the access token fails with "

```
Client error: `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/aea9a7d8-73fb-41af-987b-6fe14277421e/oauth2/v2.0/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n
    {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '\"014438b9-82dc-4a4c-9584 (truncated...)
```

"

Here is the code we have for retrieving and connecting to IMAP. I am passing actual email and password in usename and password field

```
/* Get the access Token */
$Secret = '**REMOVED**';
$AppID = '**REMOVED**';
$TenantID = '**REMOVED**';
$AccessToken = '';
try {
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'App-Token-Request']]);
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.$TenantID.'/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type'    => 'password', 
        'client_id'     => $AppID,
        'client_secret' => $Secret,
        'scope'         => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', //'https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All',// 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'username'      => '**REMOVED**',
        'password'      => '**REMOVED**',
    ], 
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
            
    $this->info(var_dump($token));
    $AccessToken = $token->access_token;

} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
    dd($e);
    return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Error requesting access token')->with('errorDetail', json_encode($e->getResponseBody()));
}
```